# Angular 2 Numeric Keyboard Launch

Tags: ios, html, cordova, angular, keyboard

I am trying to pull up a Numeric keyboard for my Angular 2 app on IOS but unable to get what I am trying to achieve. Here is my code please tell me what changes I need to make

```
<input type="number" minlength="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Month" formControlName="month" maxlength="2">
```

I have also tried changing the input type="tel" but with no luck.
I keep getting[image] while I am trying to achieve [image]

here is the article I have come across to achieve what I am trying to use but with no luck
http://danielfriesen.name/blog/2013/09/19/input-type-number-and-ios-numeric-keypad/

Answer (score 0):

Your code exactly as it is, worked for my in Safari on iOS 10.2 OSX simulator. Here's my plunker

[My Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dVFyZnCuxPgmSmZYASuy?p=preview)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}} <input type="number" minlength="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Month" formControlName="month" maxlength="2">
</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

See below[image]

Comment: But it isn't working when I actually deploy the app in an iPad with cordova. Maybe I should check into the documentation for Cordova.